# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver

Tags: osgi, h2

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver cannot be found by {my Component}.

What is the possible mistake that I would have made?

Have added the following dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.192</version>
  </dependency>
```

And the class loader will  be like this:

```
  Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
```

And I try to import the package for building an OSGi bundle as below:

```
  com.h2database.*; version ="[1.0.0,3.0.0]"
```

I was struggling for so long and your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're importing the wrong package: You are importing package com.h2database, but you're using the driver in package "org.h2"

Also, I *think* you have to import a package without the ".*" at the end

Comment: `org.h2.Driver` is the package. Thanks

Comment: You cannot Class.forName a package. So "org.h2.Driver" must be a class name for the class Driver in package org.h2.

Answer (score 1):

Never use *Class.forName(String)* in OSGi.

Always provide a classloader if you want to load classes dynamically. E.g.:

- *this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(xxx)* uses the same class loader that loaded the type of the current object.
- *MyType.class.getClassLoader.loadClass(xxx)* uses the same class loader that loaded MyType
- Class.forName(String, true, classLoader)

Also note, that you import the wrong package.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped.